# MQTT in Producer /consumer context

Tags: activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer, mqtt

we are using ActiveMQ for message Queuing with openwire transport.In this context there will be one producer and one consumer with a message listener registered. We heard about MQTT protocol and its support in activeMQ. But i saw examples only for Publisher/subscriber semantics , where subscriber need to call receive method explicitly to get the published message. Can I use mqtt with Producer/Consumer envirnment. Please give a sample..

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT protocol is based a publish / subscribe based model, it has no queuing semantics built into the protocol.  If you need Queue's then you need to stick to openwire clients or use a STOMP based client which supports both Topics and Queues.

Comment: Ok. in publish /subscribe model, there is no ack right? ie, subscribers may or may not get the published messages.But in the protocol specification, MQTT said that it is reliable. What should it mean?